# MapActivity does not work on Micromax A60

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

I have an Android application which also uses Google map apis.
The map seems to work perfectly fine on Samsung,Nexus phones.
But it throws an exception in Micromax A60.

Is there any config/setting on Micromax to enable map apis?

Log trace:

```
02-03 16:14:19.068: WARN/ResourceType(5712): Failure getting entry for 0x01080215 (t=7 e=533) in package 0: 0xffffffb5
02-03 16:14:19.068: WARN/dalvikvm(5712): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e170)
02-03 16:14:19.068: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{main.java.in.verse.em.item.android/main.java.in.verse.em.item.android.UserLocationMaps}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at main.java.in.verse.em.item.android.UserLocationMaps.onCreate(UserLocationMaps.java:34)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     ... 11 more
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:238)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     ... 21 more
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1080215
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:891)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:579)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:286)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:255)
02-03 16:14:19.078: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5712):     ... 25 more
02-03 16:14:28.928: WARN/ActivityManager(1137): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
02-03 16:14:28.938: WARN/ActivityManager(1137): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{45378bd8 main.java.in.verse.em.item.android/.UserLocationMaps}
```

Comment: Micromax prolly meddled with android...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure , but it is possible that google maps api is available only with google branded android phones . I think so because the SDK is different when you develop a maps based application .